# Any way to get the user's UPN from an email sent to a Shared mailbox?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App that monitors a shared mailbox for emails subscribing to a service.

However, in our tenant the email addresses don't always match the User Principal Name.

Is there a way to get the UPN for somebody from their email address in a Logic App?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Office 365 Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/) connector has an action:[Get user profile (V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/#get-user-profile--v2-), you could use email id to get a [GraphUser_V1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/#graphuser_v1) body, in the body it includes the User Principal Name(UPN).

[image]

Comment: I just got back to this project and tried this. Worked perfectly. Thank you.